# Onsen how to make partial swipe on item

Tags: javascript, angularjs, carousel, swipe, onsen-ui

i'm using `AngularJS` and `Onsen` framework for developing a mobile app. I added swipe to every item of a list. The code is like [this](http://codepen.io/argelius/pen/qEmjEB)

Here is the output:

[image]

I would like to have a partial swipe, not total. I mean something like this:

[image]

Do you know if i can do that with Onsen or any other workaround?
In addition do you know how to enable swipe from the right, instead of the left?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Left Menu Solution**:

Technically there is an option to set the item size for the carousel, but maybe it's going to be easier just to make the carousel smaller and cheat with the size of the items.
[**Demo 1**](http://codepen.io/IliaSky/pen/JXZBYO?editors=1100)

```
ons-carousel {
  width: 25% !important;
  overflow: visible !important;
}
.list-action-item {
  width: 400% !important;
}
```

It's ugly, but it's pretty much 2 lines of css without any thinking. :D

**Right Menu Solution**

To have the menu on the other side you can just remove the `initial-index="1"` and swap the item and menu places in the html. Afterwards again you can cheat it with some css depending on what you want to achieve. [**Demo 2**](http://codepen.io/IliaSky/pen/WwyKob?editors=1100)

In this demo I also had initially added `transform: none` to the first item, thinking that it looks better this way. Without that the items will swipe as normal. However if you do that then for smaller items you may not be able to see the item when you swipe, which is why I had originally disabled the movement.

**Right Menu Solution 2**

For the `item-width` attribute - as you can see it's an attribute for the carousel, but it's for all the items. The way carousel was made expects all items to be of the same size. You can set an item's width with css if you want, but the problem is that the carousel logic.

If you want it to behave normally it what you can do is have a fixed width for the items with `item-width`, change the size of the first one with css and add dummy items right after it for the carousel logic.

```
.list-action-item {
  width: 100% !important;
}

<ons-carousel swipeable item-width="25%" auto-scroll>
  <ons-carousel-item class="list-action-item">Fruit</ons-carousel-item>
  <ons-carousel-item class="list-action-dummy"></ons-carousel-item>
  <ons-carousel-item class="list-action-dummy"></ons-carousel-item>
  <ons-carousel-item class="list-action-dummy"></ons-carousel-item>
  <ons-carousel-item class="list-action-menu">Delete</ons-carousel-item>
</ons-carousel>
```

The existence of dummies are there so that the auto-scroll locks into to proper places. [**Demo 3**](http://codepen.io/IliaSky/pen/XdYQKB?editors=1100)

**Notes**

And in case the thing which you want to do is just do a partial swipe but still have the same item size you can just remove the `auto-scroll` attribute and then it won't auto scroll to the whole item.

Also if you think that some of the features which you want may appeal to a lot of users then feel free to say how you would like the API for them to be and it may be considered in the future.

Comment: How to set the item size? Do you mean `item-width`? How can i use it?

Comment: `item-width` it is an attribute of `ons-carousel`, not for `ons-carousel-item`.

Comment: Anyway your CSS solution doesn't work propertly. What if the content of the item is a long text instead of "Apple"? In that case when you swipe, the new item comes over the other item.

Comment: I just disabled it manually because I thought it looked better that way. You can just not disable it and it will move as expected. I updated my answer with an explanation of how you could use `item-width` for your problem.

Comment: Also feel free to see if the behaviour which you want fits just a carousel without an `auto-scroll` attribute. :)

Comment: Right Menu Solution 2: i loved it! Thank you so much!

Comment: Cannot get this to work with onsen-react. Maybe because !important is not supported in react? Does anybody have a working partial swipe example in onsen-react?